# Restoring focus on a List when it reappears (without needing to [Tab] an activation)

Tags: list, swiftui, keyboard, focus

I have a `List` with row selection supported, and tappable items that take you to another view (in other words, the `List` technically disappears).

When I exit out of the second view to return to the `List`, the row of the previously selected item still appears in a selected state. However, the `List` doesn’t re-appear with active focus. As a result, I need to [Tab] to restore focus on the selected row. Is there a way to ensure when the `List` returns into view that it does so with keyboard focus instantly set, so I can immediately press [Up] or [Down] to change the selected row with a keyboard.

Please see the video for a demonstration on a minimal example. When returning to the `List`, I try to keyboard navigate it initially but it doesn’t work, so I [tab] to restore keyboard navigation.

[image]

And here’s a minimum reproducible example.

```
struct RootView: View {

@State var items: [Int] = [0,1,2]

@State var selected: Int?

@State var detailView: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        if detailView {
            Button(action: {
                detailView = false
            }, label: {
                Text("Exit")
            })
        }
        else {
            List(items, id:\.self, selection: $selected) { index in
                Text("\(index)")
                    .tag(index)
            }
            Button(action: {
                detailView = true
            }, label: {
                Text("detail view")
            })
        }
    }.frame(width: 300, height: 420, alignment: .top)
    .onAppear {
        selected = 0
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try “ .tag(index as Int?))” have you checked if the selection is actually getting populated

Comment: Not sure what you mean... I’m already tagging it? And (index as? Int) is a conditional cast from 'Int' to 'Int' that always succeeds. Finally, as the clip shows, selection is definitely preserved. Its focus that isn’t restored when the List is recreated.

Comment: You moved the question mark. The purpose of the change in the tag is to match the type for the selection. Int isn’t Int? Sometimes that matters. If you know that selection is being preserved I would report as a bug.

Comment: Ah sorry, you’re right. But unfortunately, doesn’t make a difference. Just to be clear, how does one confirm that a selection is actually getting populated? Isn’t the fact the row is selected (albeit List inactive) implicit confirmation that it is?

Comment: Try using onChange or task(id) and see if it is triggered check the selection with a print statement

Comment: Oh yes, it certainly does print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Phillip Caudill](https://mas.to/@phill@mastodon.notsobig.co), there are actually two clever simple ways to achieve what I was after: https://mastodon.notsobig.co/@phill/111544902651110988

> 1. Use an overlay for the presentation instead (List is never gone, so focus remains):
>    https://gist.github.com/phillipcaudell/b5cb0e8b90fcfee922e4511e697b81f2
> 2. Use the .focused modifier to restore it onAppear:
>    https://gist.github.com/phillipcaudell/681bed0aff6a9ffe253e22852c0c8673

I went with 2 because I wanted to maintain the feeling of navigating away from the first screen:

```
struct RootView: View {

@State var items: [Int] = [0,1,2]

@State var selected: Int?

@State var detailView: Bool = false
    
// 1. Create state
@FocusState private var focussed: Bool

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        if detailView {
            Button(action: {
                detailView = false
            }, label: {
                Text("Exit")
            })
        }
        else {
            List(items, id:\.self, selection: $selected) { index in
                Text("\(index)")
                    .tag(index)
            }
            // 2. Apply modifier 
            .focused($focussed)
            .onAppear {
                // 3. Set to true on appear 
                focussed = true
            }
            Button(action: {
                detailView = true
            }, label: {
                Text("detail view")
            })
        }
    }
    .frame(width: 300, height: 420, alignment: .top)
    .onAppear {
        selected = 0
    }
}
```

}